# How do I solve a polynomial equation with a square root variant?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is the equation:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UARLE.jpg

I notice that the quadratic formula has been used to get the final answer. But something does not seem right because this the equation which I can simplify to, with the problem being the square root variant on the LHS:

$2(\gamma _{S}^{P}\gamma _{L}^{P})^{\frac{1}{2}} - \gamma _{L}^{P}\cos \theta _{C} - \gamma _{L}^{P} = \gamma _{L}^{D}\cos \theta _{C} - 2(\gamma _{S}^{D}\gamma _{L}^{D})^{\frac{1}{2}}$

[http://i.imgur.com/1pNscax.gif](https://i.imgur.com/1pNscax.gif)

Any advice?

Edit: to clarify, $\gamma_S^D, \gamma_S^P$ are constants

$\gamma_L^P$ is to be found as a function of $\gamma_L^D$ as given in the above problem

Comment: What is the unknown ?

Comment: gamma_SD, gamma_SP are constants

gamma_LP is to be found as a function of gamma_LD as given in the above problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation has the form

$$a\sqrt x+bx=c,$$
i.e.
$$b(\sqrt x)^2+a\sqrt x-c=0.$$
Hence
$$\sqrt x=\frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2+4bc}}{2b}.$$

Comment: would have never spotted this trick in a million years... thanks a lot